# Vulkan RAII. Got VK_ERROR_NATIVE_WINDOW_IN_USE_KHR when trying to create VkSurfaceKHR

Tags: c++, glfw, vulkan

I'm learning Vulkan_raii API and ran into this problem:

I have the source file:

```
#include <vulkan/vulkan_raii.hpp>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  glfwInit();
  GLFWwindow *window =
      glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "First window", nullptr, nullptr);
  if (!window) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to create a window!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }

  vk ::raii::Context context;
  uint32_t version = context.enumerateInstanceVersion();
  vk::ApplicationInfo appInfo{"instance", version, "instance", version, version};
  vk::InstanceCreateInfo create_info{
    vk::InstanceCreateFlags{},nullptr, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr
  };
  vk::raii::Instance instance{context, create_info};

  VkSurfaceKHR c_style_surface;
  auto res = glfwCreateWindowSurface(*instance, window, nullptr, &c_style_surface);
  if (res != VK_SUCCESS) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to create a surface! ERROR: " << res << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }
}
```

And when I compiled and run it, I got this:

```
Failed to create a surface! ERROR: -1000000001
```

I found that this error code is VK_ERROR_NATIVE_WINDOW_IN_USE_KHR. GLFW sources [describe](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/src/vulkan.c#L211) this code as "The requested window is already connected to a VkSurfaceKHR, or to some other non-Vulkan API". But I can't even imagine how my window can be already connected to the surface.

Does anyone know what causes this error and how to fix it in my example?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But I can't even imagine how my window can be already connected to the surface.

Because that's what `glfwCreateWindow` does. The library is called "GLFW" because, by default, it creates *OpenGL* windows. Which counts as "some other non-Vulkan API".

If you want to use it with Vulkan, you have to follow special rules for that. Rules that include [telling it *not* to attach OpenGL to the window](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/vulkan_guide.html#vulkan_window) via `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API)`.

Comment: It helped! Thank you, especially for the link, it helped me to solve some more bugs!